# to be suggested to do something

Tags: verbs

Is this a correct construction?

> He was suggested to arrive after they left.

I know that "I suggested him to do" is usually wrong. But what about the passive voice?

Comment: It was suggested to him that he arrive after they left.

Comment: Why use the passive?  Remember that adverbs, cliches and the passive voice should be used sparingly, but need not be avoided like the plague.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gerund and infinitives for "Suggest and Recommend".](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/62945/gerund-and-infinitives-for-suggest-and-recommend) Also [Suggest + gerund or not that is the question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/186616/) and [Can 'suggesting' (a gerund) be followed by a pronoun and an infinitive verb?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/18524/), among others.

Comment: Is there a question dealing with the suggest in the passive voice? Looking though your suggested questions I found nothing about the matter I raise in my question.

Comment: Why do you think bad grammar would become correct if used in the passive voice?

Comment: Who says that the passive voice warrants bad grammar?

Answer (score 3):

I would say it was wrong. It is not him that is being suggested but whatever he is supposed to do, so passive voice isn't applicable.

"It was suggested that he arrive ...", "Arriving after they left was suggested to him" are both acceptable alternatives using the passive voice.